# Jar size 50MB limit

Tags: codenameone

When I send an android build to the server, it is failing with the following error in (build.xml line 338)

> jar exceeds 50MB in size! Please reduce the size of the project

The build halts.

I wasn't able to find any information regarding the jar size limit. I currently have the "Basic" license.

Comment: That's a quite huge app, are you bundling some resources? Have you considered the performance of the app on different Android devices? Normal Android app should be around 3 to 5 mb.

Comment: I dont have much resources, mainly couple truetype font files and theme file.  My code base is huge. 3 to 5 mb app is actually very small. While many apps don't need to be bigger than 50 mb some do. it depends on the nature  of the app. I went to my android phone  -> Application manager. I can see that Facebook for example is 405MB , excel 202Mb , google drive 66Mb, Airbnb 127 Mb. Gmail 73 Mb. Also there are many apps that are way smaller than this but it all depends on what it's all doing.

Comment: Diamond, you were right in my case for sure. I had multiple un optimized res files. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We limit size since size this directly correlates to build time on the server and might decimate shared resources making builds slower for everyone.

So far everyone who reached the 50mb limit did it either by sticking a huge a amount of resources or just adding the android sdk JARs into the build...

There is some discussion here on [shrinking](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/shrinking-sizes-optimizing.html) the sizes of jars.

Keep in mind that 50mb will increase by a factor when deployed. E.g. Kitchen Sink is ~700kb when built but 5mb in iOS production and 13mb after going thru the Apple process to the store.

With that same factor a 50mb app will be a 500mb app in production...

Apple and Google restrict things like OTA download for apps crossing the 100mb threshold and while this might not impact a major app like Facebook it can be painful for other companies.

That's one of the major reasons we [don't support the full Java API](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html)...

I suggest unzipping the resulting JAR and looking inside to see what takes up the most space, then asking on how this can be shrunk/reduced. If it's all code that can't be optimized/reduced in any way and you don't care about the restrictions then the only workaround for you is [offline builds](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/offline-build.html), it's far from ideal but it will spare the shared resources.

Comment: Alright, I see what happened!  I had already a somewhat bad (or big)  theme.res file that I had copied / pasted 5 times to experiment with new layout. All these 5 themes were getting packaged.  Thank you very much for your feedback. Keep up the good work!